# GoDaddy Windows Plex PHP error_log not working right

Tags: php, iis-8

I'm having an issue where I get an "Internal Server Error" on my php page. To try and debug it, I attempted to use the error_log function in php. However I could not get it to write anything to the error log. Even in a simple php file:

**httpdocs/temp.php**

```
<?php
error_log("this is an error");
echo "hello";
?>
```

I would receive a basic internal server error message:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the
>   error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Web Server at xxxxxxxx.com

So I looked up how to set up the error_log properly, thinking that it was somehow not set up correctly. I found this [article](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/setup-php-error-logging-26423).

Since I am on windows I edited the .user.ini file in my httpdocs root folder and added the error_log line:

**httpdocs/.user.ini**

```
[PHP]
error_log=G:\PleskVhosts\xxxxxxxxxx.com\httpdocs\php_error.log
display_errors=off
log_errors=on
open_basedir="G:/PleskVhosts//xxxxxxxxx.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\"
safe_mode=off
sendmail_from=xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
SMTP=relay-hosting.secureserver.net
```

This [article](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-absolute-path-16024) helped me get the absolute path

I restarted the IIS application pool and created an empty php_error.log file in my httpdocs folder, however it still never wrote anything to the log file, and continued to just give the Internal Server Error. I also tried removing all the other lines in the .user.ini file besides the error_log line, restarted, and still nothing. I also tried stopping the application pool and starting it up again, still nothing.

I double checked the phpinfo and the log_errors field was set to on, and the correct directory was set for error_log. So it is seeing the .user.ini file.

I tried calling their support but they couldn't help me.

They linked me to this [article](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/get-detailed-errors-16085?v=1) about IIS error handling. I created a web.config file and put it in the httpdocs folder as it says in that article. Now I get something different. Now the output of my page is the error that I was passing to error_log. So in other words, when I visit test.php the output on the screen says:

> this is an error

Notice how the php script dies after the error? Not only should the error not be put on screen (it should be put in the php_error.log file, which is still not being written to at this point), but the php script shouldn't die afterwards unless it runs into a fatal error. I should see the "hello" from the echo and I don't.

What do I have to do to get this working properly?

My hosting plan has IIS 8 and PHP 5.4 installed.

PS. Their support basically said they cant help me any further because changing configuration files is "coding" and they dont offer coding support.

Comment: PHP 5.4 is long dead, so you have to use a newer version. Jexus Manager provides PHP Diagnostics, which can reveal whether your PHP registration on IIS is broken, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: it was a problem even when I updated to PHP 6. The problem was Godaddy had it set up that PHP didnt have file permissions by default. So every time it tried to access the error_log file it failed and crashed. Once I gave the PHP application file permissions it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP needed file read write permisions